# javascript getItem prints last array when i want to print all items in array

Tags: javascript

```
function loadImg () {
    for(let y=1;y<=nuotraukos.length;y++)
    {
        const myImg = document.createElement("img");
        myImg.src = 'images/'+ localStorage.getItem('nuotraukos',nuotraukos[y]);
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('nuotraukos',[y]));
        myImg.alt=[y]+'- img';
        myImg.width='250';
        myImg.height='200';
        const myDiv = document.querySelector(".imagePlace");
        myDiv.appendChild(myImg);
    }
}
```

so with code `myImg.src = 'images/'+ localStorage.getItem('nuotraukos',nuotraukos[y]);`
i want to print all arrays items that are inside, but when i look at the console.log it only prints last one

The idea of this 'program' is tu mix images and save when i save i put them in array and after i refresh website i want to show mixed images after pressing button 'show saved' in this case it only shows the last image of mixed images, idk what to do been stuck in this for a while

Comment: you need to `JSON.parse()` your retrieved string from local storage before you can access it as an object.

Comment: Is this code snippet working with you? for me I think localStorage.getItem() takes only one parameter not 2.

Comment: yes it only takes one the last one, i want to take all of them one by one

Comment: So, I need to know how you save images in localstorage? if you save them one by one so you have to get them one by one. and if save all array with one key so you have to get that array first and parse it to JSON then you can iterate on it.

Comment: `getItem` only takes 1 argument. As @AhmedIbrahim said we need to see how you are saving these items in local storage to answer how to read them all. We also needsome info on what `nuotraukos` is.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated: people read this about 348257347213258 times: `for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {`. See `y = 1` and `y <=`, siren goes "weewoo weewoo"

Comment: `myImg.src = 'images/'+ JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('nuotraukos'))[y];` changed it and got error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token j in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLButtonElement.loadImg (script.js:53)`

Comment: @Justas.P Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you are using this code to save in local storage

```
    for(var i=0;i<=7;i++)
    {
        let removeImg = document.querySelector('img');
        removeImg.remove();
        const myImg = document.createElement("img");
        myImg.src = 'images/'+nuotraukos[i];
        myImg.alt=[i]+'- img';
        myImg.width='250';
        myImg.height='200';
        const myDiv = document.querySelector(".imagePlace");
        myDiv.appendChild(myImg);
        localStorage.setItem('nuotraukos',nuotraukos[i]); // ********
    }
```

The line which I refer to with `********` is saying that you are override the `nuotraukos` item and it will be the last element in the array.

So, you need to save the array first after initiating your images array

```
localStorage.setItem('nuotraukos', JSON.stringify(nuotraukos)); // save all array elements in one item
```

And when you need to load the array you have to load it and parse to JSON then iterate in the for loop. And note that `getItem()` method takes only one parameter which is the key.

```
function loadImg () {
    let imgArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('nuotraukos')); // get array and parse it
    for(let y=0; y <imgArray.length; y++) // iterate from 0 to length
    {
        const myImg = document.createElement("img");
        myImg.src = 'images/'+  imgArray[y];
        myImg.alt= y +'- img';
        myImg.width='250';
        myImg.height='200';
        const myDiv = document.querySelector(".imagePlace");
        myDiv.appendChild(myImg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to parse the items Array :

```
function loadImg () {
const localnuotraukos= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('nuotraukos'))



for(let y=1;y<=nuotraukos.length;y++)
{
    const myImg = document.createElement("img");
    myImg.src = 'images/'+localnuotraukos[y] ;
    console.log(localnuotraukos[y]);
    myImg.alt=[y]+'- img';
    myImg.width='250';
    myImg.height='200';
    const myDiv = document.querySelector(".imagePlace");
    myDiv.appendChild(myImg);
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more what is the expected output of this line ```localStorage.getItem('nuotraukos',[y])```?

Comment: opps I forgot to delete that line I copied the orignal code portion from the question to use in my answer